# HKHealthStore preferred units not supported for universal apps?

Tags: ios, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I have a universal iOS app that references HealthKit. When the app is installed on an iPhone the app uses HKHealthStore to retrieve health data and when it is on an iPad I skip the HealthKit queries by checking if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable is false. This all works well but in order to have the app run on an iPad I have to remove the "healthkit" entry from my app's .plist under "Required device capabilities". This makes sence because the iPad doesn't have healthkit on it so requiring it makes it so the app won't install on the iPad. All of  this has already been done in an app I have submitted to the app store and has been approved.

Now I am making an app update and I want to show unit preferences that a user may have manually adjusted in the Health App. The documentation for HKHeathStore says you can do this using the [preferredUnitsForQuantityTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014708-CH1-DontLinkElementID_27) method. However, calling this method from my iPhone app gives me the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.}
```

Except I have the healthkit entitlement in my app id already. If I add the "healthkit" entery under the "Required device capabilities" section of my .plist, then this error goes away and I get the desired results. But this is not a solution for me because then I can't install the app on an iPad.

My question is, how can I support a universal app where the iPhone version can make a successful call to HKHealthStore.preferredUnitsForQuantityTypes?

EDIT
Here is what my .entitlements file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.com.mycompany.myapp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was based on reading your question incorrectly.  What are the exact steps you took to remove "healthkit" from "Required device capabilities"?

Comment: I went into my app's .plist file and under the <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key> section I removed the <string>healthkit</string> entry. This is the only way I have found that an app that references HealthKit can actually be installed on an iPad (even though the iPad code doesn't use HealthKit).

Comment: That sounds correct.  What are the contents of your app's .entitlements file?

Comment: I have updated my post above to show what the entitlements file contains. It kind of looks like an Apple bug, where they are looking in the .plist when that method is called instead of at the entitlements file.

Comment: Perhaps try filing a but with Apple and attach a copy of a project that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening here. There was a threading issue between when the HKHealthStore was requesting access to health types and requesting the preferred units. I'm not sure why the .plist entry fixes this issue... but moving the preferred units request into the completion block of the HKHealthStore's requesting access method fixed the issue.